# mvc3 how can i have automatic expirations

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, compilation

Ok so I have an area where people can create OpenHouse listings for a period of 14 days then the listing is expired and should be deleted, my question is; is there some type of way to have the Database delete listings automatically? This is the simple code I have below it works but it is not optimal

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        openhouse mydate= new openhouse();
        if (mydate.expired > DateTime.Now)
        {
            db.openhouses.Remove(mydate);
        }
     }
```

That as you can tell is in my Global.asax but **the issue is that listings only get deleted if I Compile the application** I am thinking there must be a more efficient way to do this than me compiling every day just for that, any suggestions would be very appreciated ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database itself won't provide any timers or scheduled tasks for you (at least SQLLite won't). You have to program a task that cleans up expired listings, for that, you have several options:

- Using a task scheduled within your own ASP.net application
- Using a task (a separate application) scheduled and managed by your hosting provider. If you are on the cloud, your cloud provider most likely has the capability to do this for you.

If you want to go with the first option, take a look at [Quartz](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/). I have a WorkerRole on Azure than uses Quartz to do things like what you need here. It's fairly simple to setup, here is an example:

```
        // Initialize Quartz
        ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        _scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
        _scheduler.JobFactory = new NinjectJobFactory(_kernel);

        DateTimeOffset morning = DateBuilder.NewDateInTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time"))
            .AtHourMinuteAndSecond(5, 30, 0)
            .Build();

        // Schedule task for email being sent to people who have not signed up after their trial expiry
        IJobDetail userFeedbackJobDetail = JobBuilder.Create<LostUserFeedbackRequestJob>().WithIdentity("User Feedback Emails").Build();
        ITrigger dailyTriggerForUserFeedback = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("Daily Trigger (User Feedback)")
            .StartAt(morning)
            .WithSimpleSchedule(schedule => schedule.WithInterval(TimeSpan.FromDays(1)).RepeatForever())
            .ForJob(userFeedbackJobDetail)
            .Build();
        _scheduler.ScheduleJob(userFeedbackJobDetail, dailyTriggerForUserFeedback);

        // Finally, start the scheduler
        _scheduler.Start();
```

This sends an email everyday asking for feedback from users who have not elected to use the services of one of my projects after their trial period has finished. The job is run everyday at 5:30 a.m.

Comment: Thank you very much that is perfect, I'm going to start on that.